# Рисование в Java

Tags: java

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы при любых изменениях фрэйма, нарисованное на JPanel не стиралось? И логично ли использовать для рисования JPanel?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. надо запоминать массив нарисованных точек и прорисовывать их заново каждый раз при обновлении панели.

Comment: А если много объектов?

Comment: не имеет значения, сколько объектов

Comment: А можно небольшой пример?

Comment: количество объектов не влияет на количество пикселей...

Answer (score 1):

Тут правда непонятно, что имеется ввиду под изменениями фрейма. Но вообще общий принципе такой: вы рисуете на backgroungImage, а этот image затем перерисовываете на JPanel при любых изменениях фрейма (например, при увеличении или сжатии)
Для примера можете посмотреть код примитивного графического редактора: [Графический редактор на java](http://metanit.com/java/sources/3.php)

Comment: Т.е. мы не рисуем на панели?

Comment: нет, мы не напрямую на JPanel рисуем, мы рисуем на image - он находится в памяти, а при всех растягиваниях формы, при которых может измениться размер JPanel, мы перерисовываем изображение на JPanel. Напрямую на JPanel не надо рисовать